# Adobe Illustrator cc color picker

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

So my color picker looks like this:

[image]

I want the old one but don't know how to change it. It's really hard to work with this one and I can't choose the color I want. Please help :(

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever seen a color picker, other than the one you showed, inside Illustrator.  Maybe I've been missing something this whole time?  Alternatively, maybe you are thinking of the color palette that can be found in Window > Color?

Comment: I am guessing you're talking about Hue "H:", make sure that circle is checked. Right now you're only changing the green value of RGB.

Comment: @AndrewH Whoa, good catch!  I never even saw that OP had selected the Green channel.  I think you're right.

Comment: @AndrewH As it is the correct one, would you mind making that an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about Hue "H:", **make sure the H: circle is checked**. Right now you're only changing the green value of RGB.

Comment: Awesome. I've used adobe for many years but guess I've never actually clicked the bubbles (just changed values manually). Adding search terms so more people find it in SERPs: color picker broken messed up no white not showing other colors.